# A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined

Tags: reactjs

This is my ContactUs component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
class ContactUs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      contactUs: {
        telephone: "",
        name: "",
        emailAddress: "",
      },
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <div className="form-element">
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="name"
            value={this.state.contactUs.name}
            onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-element">
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            value={this.state.contactUs.emailAddress}
            onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-element">
          <label>Telephone:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="telephone"
            value={this.state.contactUs.telephone}
            onChange={this.handletelephoneChange}
          />
        </div>
        <Button onClick={this.sendEmail}>Send Email</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleFirstNameChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ contactUs: { name: event.target.value } });
  };
  handletelephoneChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ contactUs: { telephone: event.target.value } });
  };
  handleEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ contactUs: { emailAddress: event.target.value } });
  };

 sendEmail = () => {
    console.log("Name is " + this.state.contactUs.name);
    console.log("Email address is " + this.state.contactUs.emailAddress);
    console.log("Telephone is " + this.state.contactUs.telephone);
  };
}

export default ContactUs;
```

These are questions related to above component.

1. When I add something to one of three elements in the component, I received following error. How can I get rid of the error?

*Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components*

2. After I filled Name, telephone and email and press the button, I received following output.

Name is undefined
Email address is undefined
Telephone is Test Telephone

Why the output does not contain the values for Name and email address?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Writing this `this.setState({ contactUs: { telephone: event.target.value } })` overrides existing `contactUs` state completely  as `contactUs` is an `object`, 

Replace this by `this.setState({ contactUs: {...this.state.contactUs, telephone: event.target.value } })` so that you donot get undefined in final values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Issues

1. React uses [Synthetic Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) that are quickly nullified and returned back to the event pool. By the time the state update is processed the event object has been nullified and your state values set to undefined. This causes the controlled to uncontrolled input warning.
2. The other issue is not correctly shallow copying the existing nested `contactUs` state when new values arrive for other inputs. React's `this.setState` only merges root level state, all deeper state should be manually merged.

## Solution

Save the input value ***before*** enqueueing the state update. Use a functional state update to access the previous state.

```
handleFirstNameChange = (event) => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    contactUs: {
      ...prevState.contactUs, // <-- copy other nested state
      name: value,
    },
  }));
};
```

## Suggestion

To make your code a bit more **DRY** you can define a single `onChange` handler to handle all the inputs.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  const { id, value } = event.target;
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    contactUs: {
      ...prevState.contactUs,
      [id]: value
    }
  }));
};
```

The inputs. Ensure all the `id` attributes match their react state counterpart. Use the same handler for each.

```
<div className="form-element">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="name"
    value={this.state.contactUs.name}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
</div>
<div className="form-element">
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input
    type="email"
    id="emailAddress"
    value={this.state.contactUs.emailAddress}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
</div>
<div className="form-element">
  <label>Telephone:</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="telephone"
    value={this.state.contactUs.telephone}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
</div>
```

[image: Edit a-component-is-changing-a-controlled-input-to-be-uncontrolled-this-is-likely-ca]

Answer (score 5):

The warning "A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled" occurs when an input value is initialized to undefined but is later changed to a different value. To fix the warning, initialize the input value to an empty string,

e.g. `value={message || ''}.`

Comment: This is a different error than what was asked about